# Random Assoc Array Value in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, random, key

i have an assoc array which comes from an

```
mysqli_fetch_assoc()
```

function. I would get a value from a random key of it...

Basically, I just need to pick an ICAO up randomly from the db.

So I've found this function

```
function shuffle_assoc($list) { 
    if (!is_array($list)) return $list; 

    $keys = array_keys($list); 
    shuffle($keys); 
    $random = array(); 
    foreach ($keys as $key) { 
        $random[$key] = $list[$key]; 
    }
 return $random; 
}
```

And I tried to code:

```
$sql = "SELECT icao FROM airport_list";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while ($airports = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $random_airport = shuffle_assoc($airports);
}

var_dump($random_airport);
```

The "var-dumped" result is

```
array(1) { ["icao"]=> string(4) "ZYTX" }
```

which seems to be an array that never changes while reloading the page, so... I think it's wrong.

Comment: Are you trying to pull random rows from the table?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/3a7aab73448ac12e22282de2a3ad5363 that's the table, i'm trying to get a random 'icao' from all of these.

Comment: Can you not just do a `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` and pull that column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify this whole process by pulling a random row from the table by amending your query as can be seen below:

```
SELECT icao FROM airport_list ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```